# Oracle PL/SQL - Fetch cursor columns into another cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am attempting to fetch columns of a cursor lrefcur_equip_work into another cursor.

```
lrefcur_equip_work := equipment_work_type_lib.get_equipment_type_list
                        (pn_equipment_type_id => lr_equipment_type.equipment_type_id);
```

This returns data in columns

```
EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID   WORK_TYPE_ID
```

The column WORK_TYPE_ID is  a primary key for table WORK_TYPES.

I am needing a refcursor of WORK_TYPES records, fetched using the primary key WORK_TYPE_ID fetched from my original refcursor.

Using pseudo code (that doesn't work), this is essentially what i'm trying to do:

```
lrefcur_equip_work SYS_REFCURSOR;
lrefcur_new        SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN

 lrefcur_equip_work := equipment_work_type_lib.get_equipment_type_list(pn_equipment_type_id => lr_equipment_type.equipment_type_id);

LOOP
  FETCH lrefcur_equip_work INTO equip_work_record
    OPEN lrefcur_new FOR
      SELECT * from work_types where work_type_id = equip_work_record.work_type_id;
```

Of course this would only retrieve one record, as I'm pretty sure refcursors don't work dynamically like this. Would there be another way to construct this second refcursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't "fetch into" a cursor, it doesn't make any sense in Oracle.

You can do something like this, but it isn't a great design:

```
DECLARE
  lrefcur_equip_work SYS_REFCURSOR;
  lrefcur_new        SYS_REFCURSOR;
  work_types_rec     work_type%rowtype;
BEGIN

 lrefcur_equip_work := equipment_work_type_lib.get_equipment_type_list
                         (pn_equipment_type_id => lr_equipment_type.equipment_type_id);

LOOP
  FETCH lrefcur_equip_work INTO equip_work_record
    OPEN lrefcur_new FOR
      SELECT * 
        into work_types_rec     
        from work_types where work_type_id = equip_work_record.work_type_id;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (work_types_rec.work_type_id);
```

Are you forced to use `equipment_work_type_lib.get_equipment_type_list` as built, or can you write something more useful instead?  Something like:

```
DECLARE
  lrefcur_new        SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN lrefcur_new FOR
    SELECT * 
      from work_types where work_type_id IN
         (/* Whatever query you are running in equipment_work_type_lib.get_equipment_type_list */)

END;
```

Or you could change the function to return a table TYPE:

```
create type t_equip_list_tab is table of number;

function get_equipment_type_list (...)
  return t_equip_list_tab;
```

Then:

```
DECLARE
  lrefcur_new        SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN lrefcur_new FOR
    SELECT * 
      from work_types where work_type_id IN
         TABLE (equipment_work_type_lib.get_equipment_type_list
                 (pn_equipment_type_id => lr_equipment_type.equipment_type_id)
               );
```

Comment: Would this actually populate lrefcur_new? unfortunately i need to return a refcursor type, rather than loop and display each work_type_id.

And my function 'equipment_work_type_lib.get_equipment_type_list' can return whatever I want, but no matter what I need to join these refcursors by work_type_id, and I'm not sure how else I would do it.

Comment: You can't join ref cursors.  I have updated my answer with some other ideas you could look into.

Comment: Wondering why I hadn't thought of that first solution you added. Thank you much!